# Number of rows in SQL dump

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, dump

Is there any way to check how many rows are in an SQL dump file? I have a large 32GB dump, and wanted to check how many rows are in the file.

I am using a windows machine with a MySQL server,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- You should be safely calculate using `wc -l filename.sql`
- On windows you may use following in command prompt: `findstr /R /N "^" filename.sql | find /C ":"`

As such not a part of question but out of intereset, you can also list content of the 32G dump using [mysqldumpsplitter](https://github.com/kedarvj/mysqldumpsplitter):
`mysqldumpsplitter.sh --source filename --desc` [[More how-tos]](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/how-to-recipes-for-mysqldumpsplitter)

Comment: I am in a windows environment and not a *nix, does this exist in the windows world? Thanks for the comment

Comment: findstr /R /N "^" filename.sql | find /C ":"

Updated answer above... Why would you want a line count though?

Comment: You could use cygwin - a load of deadly unix utilities for Windows.